# c - char variable proceeds without taking input

Tags: c

I have written a program to take input of two numbers and either add or subtract the numbers depending the operation specified.
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float i, j, k;
    char a;
    printf("This is a program to add or subs two number.\n");
    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf("%f", &i);
    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%f", &j);
    printf("Give your choice(+ or -): ");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    switch(a){
        case '+' :
            k = i + j;
            printf("Sum = %f\n", k);
            break;
        case '-' :
            k = i - j;
            printf("Difference = %f\n", k);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Cannot do this operation\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program takes input for the two numbers but skips input for operation and runs the default case. Please help!
(I am using gcc compiler).

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! , Could you please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Thank you very much! , btw how do i upvote a comment?

Comment: @MohitGarg Mouse hover on the left side of the comment. A tiny little icon with an up arrow should appear. Also there will be a flag icon which can be used to raise moderator attention if there are inappropriate comments (rudeness, spam etc).

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, but i think that is for a person with a certain minimum reputation! . I think I would have to wait for it!

Answer (score 2):

The %c conversion specifier won't automatically skip any leading whitespace, so if there's a stray newline in the input stream (from a previous entry, for example) the scanf call will consume it immediately.

One way around the problem is to put a blank space before the conversion specifier in the format string:

scanf(" %c", &a);
The blank in the format string tells scanf to skip leading whitespace, and the first non-whitespace character will be read with the %c conversion specifier.

-Aditya